# Swap contents of std::vector in constant time - is it possible?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I'm using `std::vector` to store an image in my *Image* class. I'm having a bit trouble understanding how they work. A function which rotates the image:

```
void Image :: resize (int width, int height)
{
    //the image in the object is "image"

    std::vector<uint8_t> vec;  //new vector to store rotated image

    // rotate "image" and store in "vec"

    image = vec; // copy "vec" to "image" (right?)

    //vec destructs itself on going out of scope
}
```

Is there any way to prevent the last copy? Like in Java, just by switching references? It would be nice if any copying is prevented.

Comment: In C++11 you could do: `image = std::move(vec)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `std::vector::swap`:

```
image.swap(vec);
```

This is a essentially a pointer swap, the contents are transferred rather than copied. It is perfectly  valid since you don't care about the contents of `vec` after the swap.

In C++11 you can "move" the contents of `vec` into `image`:

```
image = std::move(vec);
```

This operation has essentially the same effect, except that the state of `vec` is less well defined (it in a self consistent state but you cannot make any assumptions about its contents... but you don't care anyway because you know you are discarding it immediately).

Comment: In C++03 `swap` is the way to go.

Comment: Swapping in constant time? Thanks this is what I needed.

Comment: @Bruce I added a C++11 option.

Comment: Note that the state of `vec` is unspecified, but valid. So one could essentially `clear()` the vector, perhaps `resize()`, and continue using the moved-from object.

Comment: In theory one could probably argue, that using `std::move` might be faster than `swap`, since it doesn't need to care for the _source_ instance.